# How tensorflow reshape a tensor with dimension of None, like this [None,2,2,1]?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

The error is:

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. 
>   Contents: [None, 4]. 
>   Consider casting elements to a supported type.

```
import tensorflow as tf
xs=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2,2,1],name='x-input')
reshaped_xs=tf.reshape(xs,[None,4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(reshaped_xs)
```

The tensorflow version is: 1.4.0

```
docker run -d  --restart=always -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:1.4.0
```

So how to fix this? TKS!

Comment: 1. dynamic shape can be obtained via `tf.shape`; 2. the placeholder `xs` must be fed with some values in order to be evaluated: `print(sess.run(reshaped_xs, feed_dict={xs: some_array}))`

Comment: Yes,it works!TKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reshape the placeholder simply use `-1` for the unknown dimension. You must also feed a value to the placeholder when you use `sess.run`. This will work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2, 2, 1], name='x-input')

reshaped_xs = tf.reshape(xs, [-1, 4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = [[[[0.], [0.]], [[0.], [0.]]]]
    print(sess.run(reshaped_xs, feed_dict={xs: x}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reshape a placeholder, it reserve a memory space for the object to be passed in feed dict, the None means the memory will be allocated dynamic,in your case you are reshaping a non allocated memory to another fixed size of memory,it might be syntax correct but i doubt if you run it in ipython it will work.

Comment: You can reshape placeholders like any other tensors. Tensorflow does not allocate any memory for computation until the actual computation after a `sess.run` call takes place. And when `sess.run` is called and the placeholders are fed, the shapes become known, and Tensorflow can allocate the needed size of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what the question and the comment with the answer means. Had to clarify for myself first. Something similar.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None))
x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, shape=[tf.shape(x)[0], 2,2,1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    _, x_reshaped_result = sess.run([x, x_reshaped], feed_dict={x: np.random.random(16).reshape(4, 2, 2, 1)})
    print (x_reshaped_result.shape)
```